# How to Access and Inspect `edge://translate-internals` via CMD-Batch or PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, microsoft-edge, translation

I've encountered a specific issue with the Microsoft Edge browser, particularly related to its translation feature. Similar to the situation described in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/edge/comments/lu5ckd/how_to_force_translation_of_a_page_in_edgetwo/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), I am trying to find a way to programmatically query or inspect the state/content of the `edge://translate-internals` page using command-line tools like CMD-batch scripts or PowerShell.

From what I understand, `edge://translate-internals` is an internal page in Microsoft Edge that details the browser's built-in translation functionality. However, accessing and modifying this page outside of the Edge browser interface, especially through command-line interfaces, doesn't seem straightforward.

I'm looking for a way to script or automate interactions with this page, preferably using CMD-batch or PowerShell. The goal is to get insights into the translation feature's status or configurations and possibly modify them programmatically.

Could anyone advise on whether this is feasible and, if so, provide guidance on achieving it? Any tips, sample scripts, or pointing towards relevant documentation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: General browser automation (Selenium WebDriver, Playwright) could probably do it. This will require proper programming though. PowerShell is ill-suited for that and Batch is entirely out of the question.

Comment: @DanielB , thanks for the response, though this is not really browser automation. These are Edge's internal settings, which I believe should be exposed to the command line tools such as cmd and/or PowerShell.

Comment: Not sure I follow, sorry. You may want it to be exposed, but it is virtually guaranteed it is not. As with most things in GUI applications. IMHO, the way forward is to work with what’s there and what’s possible.

Comment: @Foad what makes you say "should"? I can't think of any browser exposing settings to CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the page to a file and then manipulate the file.

The only option I have found for that is :

```
start msedge --headless --print-to-pdf=[pdf-destination-path] [website-path]
```

You may then use a utility to convert the PDF to text, and
further manipulate the text file with PowerShell or other
utilities.